# Flash as3 error movieClip : 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: input

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;

function setPuzzle(MovieClip: input): void {
    //input.rotation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
}
```

please help me.. i'm new in as3... I can't fix this error :"(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function setPuzzle(MovieClip: input)` -> `function setPuzzle(input: MovieClip)`

To learn about as3 `function` check out that article http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html